# Login form in popup

Tags: customization

I'm using WP3 with the defaul theme. I would like people to register before submit a comment.

What I'm trying to do is having a link instead of the comment form that says something like "Leave a comment". Clicking this link would open a popup window with a login/register form or the comment form if people already signed in.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation would be to use a plug-in like [Lightbox Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lightbox-plus/) to power your link.  Clicking the link would load your standard login form inside a lightbox.  You could then automatically redirect to the same page so that, once logged in, users can leave a comment.

Basically, you'd dynamically build your link to be something link this:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fyoursite.com%2Fpostname" 
   rel="lightbox[login-form]" 
   title="Please login to comment">Login to Comment</a>
```

This would load the login form in a lightbox and set it to redirect to the post upon successful authentication.  This *might* be all you need, but I haven't tested it ... so give it a try and, if needed, add some other scripts to reload the page upon successful login.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work, but the link just directs me to the login page. Should Lightbox Plus automatically pick up on the `rel="lichtbox[login-form]"` ?

Comment: Nevermind, using classes (one of the options) it works. Thanks!

Comment: What I did for the login/register form on http://2010.wphonors.com is created a separate file with the login form, and include it into the hidden div in the footer of the site. Then when you click on the login/register menu item it is displayed in a thickbox.